# Hiding ONE particular street name on map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit

Is it possible in Google Maps API or iOS Mapkit to **hide ONE particular street label**? I have done a lot of research and could not find a way except to stylize google map to hide all street name labels. I an open to any other free Maps API as long as it can be integrated in xCode/Swift/iOS.

Comment: Just out of genuine curiosity what is your reasoning for wanting to do this?

Comment: Classified right now  :)

Comment: Haha oh okay that's too bad I really was curious.

Comment: Promise to declassify it when I can!

Comment: If you ask yourself would anyone else ever want this feature and the answer is no, chances are no one has made an API for it. Are you open to suggestions of ways you might try to hack around this limitation?

Comment: Any update on this? I'm interested...

Comment: No, no one seems to have a solution

Answer (score 2):

If you used a mapping solution based on Open Street Maps (OSM) such as Mapbox, then you **could** go to the Open Street Maps and edit that street out. Mapbox is nearly a drop in replacement for MapKit.

Of course, you don't mention **why** you need to remove a street and if you were to edit OSM, it should be for a legitimate reason.

Comment: It is for the purpose of an app I am creating and the hiding of street name is only temporary. Not sure, what you mean by "editing" OSM. It wont be a legitimate map correction.

Comment: OSM is an open-source, community-edited map of the world. You're correct that editing it for non-legitimate reasons would not be appropriate. You can also get a snapshot of the OSM data and edit your copy. You would need to run your own map tile service, so this would be a bit more effort.

Comment: That sounds doable. You think I can download a snapshot of OSM data and then then programatically hide street labels at run-time? Also any resource for running my tile service? Can't do that with Mapbox, can I?

Comment: You know...I started thinking about this again. Since Mapbox GL is open source, you could fork their code and just hack the label drawing to ignore certain streets, or even change them. That way you don't need to change the map data, just how it gets displayed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Unfortunately, that seems a little out of my league (C++ etc). My strength is in Swift/iOS